# Can I limit scope of jQuery version I need using noConflict() if other scripts' loading order is unknown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, concurrency, callback

I want to asynchronously include a specific version of jQuery in a page I don't control (e-commerce platform) and only use it in my script. The page may load other scripts, which may also want to do the same thing, and I don't know the order in which the page includes my script vs others.

Using `jQuery.noConflict([removeAll])`, can I ensure that:

1. my script gets the right version of jQuery
2. I don't overwrite jQuery version for anyone else?

I think this question is different from most other multiple jQuery version questions because people make assumptions about script inclusion order and don't use asynchronous jQuery loading with callbacks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at this (could someone confirm this is ok?):

**myscript.js**

```
(function() {

  var myJQuery;

  function loadjQuery(url, callback) {
    var runCallbackOnSuccess = function() {
      if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") {
        myJQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);   // NOTICE THIS LINE
        callback();
      }
    };
    var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    scriptTag.setAttribute("src", url);
    scriptTag.onload = runCallbackOnSuccess; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
  }

  function doSomethingInMyScript() {
    myJQuery(document).ready(....);
  }

  loadjQuery("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-A.B.C.min.js", doSomethingInMyScript);
})();
```

**otherscript.js** (outside my control, but assuming it's like this)

```
(function() {
  function loadjQuery(url, callback) {
    <same as above, but without the noConflict() call>
  }

  function doSomethingInOtherScript() {
    jQuery(document).ready(....);
  }

  loadjQuery("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-X.Y.Z.min.js", doSomethingInOtherScript);
})();
```

Will this code work regardless of:

1. whether the page includes myscript.js or otherscript.js first
2. whether the callback functions for myscript.js or otherscript.js is executed first?

I suspect it should be fine as long as the callback functions are executed immediately after each respective jQuery is loaded, with no possibility of code from the other script interleaving between jQuery loaded and callback executed.

Comment: Didn't you get `Unexpected token` for `function() {}();` ?

Comment: Thanks, added parentheses.

Comment: I tried that once before and was told to post my idea as an answer. :)

Comment: @JanŻankowski - Did you ever confirm that this works without issue?

Comment: @Tim - sorry, don't remember the context, and don't have time right now to verify this again! :(